# Auto Push Screen

Tags: xcode

I am Newbie to Xcode and this also my first question .
Here is my question :  **|** I have a ViewController1 and I create another one (call it ViewController2). When I launch my app it will show up the ViewController |(Lead to Problem)***|***( Now come the problem) ***and then after 5 seconds (or x seconds) it will automatically push to ViewController2 Screen*** . Can I really do that ? 
Thank you for reading my question . I am a Vietnamese so my English skills can make you hard to understand what I say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to guarantee that the class for the UIViewController is set correctly. Look at Identity Inspector and look what class is selected.
After this, if you're using storyboard, with a Navigation Controller, verify the first arrow that points for the view that will appear in the start of application.

[image]

Comment: Can you help me with screen or code or something,please ?Because I don't know what is storyboard , Navagation Controller ... And Thank you for your replied

Comment: There is no code. Only configuration properties. In your interface, the archive that contains is .xib or .storyboard ?

Comment: I am using interface with xib , but I don'y know hơ to set prerties as you say. Can upload some screenshot please ? and tks for your reply

Comment: I put a screenshot for you. You must click on the border of your view to see that menu.